# I saw the 'z4root' application on the Droid market just now. Is it safe to use on my Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-s, rooting

Anybody used the **Z4ROOT** program to root/unroot his device ? Can I use it on my **Samsung Galaxy S** phone ?

**Is it a real root / unroot process ?** I am a developer myself and know how much damage you can do on a computer if you have too much power and too little knowledge.

However, a true root / unroot program seems ideal. That way I can root the device if necessary (f.i. to grab a screen dump or whatever) and unroot the device immediatly afterwards (until such time I really know what I'm doing - if ever :)  ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've rooted my SGS with z4root and it was a very smooth process! I can highly recommend z4root!

And while you're at it, continue with installing [One Click Lag Fix](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ryanzas-oclf-2-0/com.rc.QuickFixLagFix) to make your SGS lag a lot less! I did it, and haven't looked back since. OCLF is made by the same guy who made z4root, but for some weird reason, OCLF can, by itself, only root pre-froyo phones. But that's not a big problem, you just need 2 apps instead of one :)

Answer (score 2):

I used z4root on Samsung Galaxy 3, and it was quite smooth.

The easiest way to root(unroot) android.

Answer (score 1):

[The XDA post for z4root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833953) says that it is 100% compatible with Samsung Galaxy S and will provide a permanent root option.

> V1.2.0 : Unroot support, fix for
>   devices with small max file size such
>   as I5700, binaries in xbin rather than
>   bin

So it says it will unroot?  I have not used this method to root any phones, so I can not vouch for it.

Answer (score 0):

Z4root was a very nice simple app (at least, v. 1.3.0 worked for SGS on *Froyo 2.2*),
but after I upgraded Samsung Galaxy S to *Gingerbread* (**2.3.5**),
this rooting method became nonfunctional.

The phone can be rooted with [SuperOneClick](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/how-do-i-root-my-samsung-galaxy-s) though.