# How do I root my Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rooting

How do I root my Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000?

Answer (score 7):

Enable *USB debugging* from `settings -> Applications -> Development` then connect your phone to a machine that has [*SuperOneClick*](http://shortfuse.org/) installed. Open *SuperOneClick*, click the `root` button and...*viola* :)