# How can I remove the SIM lock from a Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sim-unlocking

I bought one from bell Canada, and I can't put in a SIM card from any other service provider. Does anyone know how to unlock this phone?

Comment: You might want to post the 2nd problem as a different question..

Comment: I was able to access the phones internal memory by selecting usb mass storage from usb settings but I still cannot connect the device to samsung kies as MTP usb device fails to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unlock your phone, use [GalaxSim Unlock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spocky.galaxsimunlock).

You need root for this app. If you don't have root, the app will give you instructions on how to root your phone.

Comment: I have installed  GalaxSim Unlock but the instructions to root from XDA developers are quite complex and I would not want to risk bricking my phone by using rooting instructions for another model phone. Anyone with instructions for samsung galaxy s GT_I900M from bell Canada running android version 2.2 FROYO.

Comment: @LeroyKayanda Why don't you try rooting with SuperOneClick from shortfuse.org instead? It's easier. I can't seem to access the site right now though. Try it later?

Comment: Ive tried super one click but it has this problem of freezing and not responding when it reaches a point of waiting for device.. Ive now downloaded odin. A link to how I can root my galaxy s with odin would be appreciated.

Comment: @Leroy Kayanda There's a lot of Guides if you search on Google. Here is an example using Odin: http://www.android.gs/root-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000-android-2-3-6-gingerbread-xxjvu-firmware-with-cf-root/

Comment: @LeroyKayanda Make sure you have your device drivers installed for ADB.

Comment: Rooting the Galaxy S is pretty easy: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/how-do-i-root-my-samsung-galaxy-s

Answer (score 1):

You can unlock your Samsung Galaxy S using unlock code .You can get unlock codes from the network provider or online vendors like [Unlocking4U.com](http://www.unlocking4u.com/samsung-galaxy-s/rs16wp9/) . But, Most Network providers will provide the unlock code only if the contract period is over . From Online vendors you can get the Unlock code at any time for a small price.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know if your phone is CDMA or GSM. If it's a CDMA phone then it cannot be unlocked.

GSM phones can be unlocked to make it work with other networks. If you want to unlock your phone for free you can root your phone but it is at your own risk. Also rooting voids your warranty.

Safer method is to get an unlock code from the unlock code providers like http://www.samsungsimunlock.com/ There are other unlock code providers like http://www.unlocking4u.com but there are slightly expensive.

Unlocking phones is restricted in some countries. Recently US passed a law where unlocking phones is illegal that are manufactured after Jan 26th 2013. Phones manufactured before that date can be unlocked. Please check your local laws before unlocking.

Answer (score 0):

Installed the adb drivers for samsung galaxy s. Enabled the phone to be rooted using superoneclick and finally unlocked using Galaxysim Unlock. Thanks for the tips.