# Why is my Samsung Galaxy S still on Android 2.2.1?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I have tried by using samsung kies but it says there are no updates. i have even tried to update it within the phone (software update). Other people are on android 2.3 but i am still on 2.2.1 and it won't update

Comment: Let me make a guess: The SGS was released 2010, has already 3 successors (S2, S3, S4) -- I wouldn't wonder if it would have fallen out of support. But according to [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9000_galaxy_s-3115.php), official support ends with 2.3. Could you provide a few more details on your device, e.g. if it's branded? Maybe it's your carrier blocking the update (as he had to include his adjustments, i.e. the branding stuff, again otherwise -- which would mean additional work for an "outdated device").

Comment: i bought it from T-mobile on a contract

Comment: That's what I've thought. So T-mobile had to pick the latest update, adapt it, and roll it out. I could imagine they ignore such an "old device". Try contacting their service, asking for the update. If they refuse, an alternative would be to have it unlocked (here T-mobile certainly won't refuse), root it (this they won't do, you must do that) and flash a custom ROM. This way you might even get 4.x onto the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've got your device with a contract, this added a special barrier to updates. Short explanation how that goes:

1. Google (or rather the AOSP, [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/)) releases a new Android version. This is usually immediately available to Nexus devices -- but...
2. Device manufacturers need to adapt it to their hardware (drivers etc.) and, in many cases, their special "skinning" ([HTC Sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htc_sense), Samsung [Tourchwiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz), [Motorola Blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoblur), etc), which again at least delays availability of this update
3. Carriers using their special branding (boot logo, special apps, and more)

So if there's a new Android version released by the AOSP does not necessarily mean it becomes available for all Android devices. It might get stuck already in step 2 if a manufacturer decides to no longer support a device (in your case that happened after the 2.3 release, so 2.3 is the latest "official version" available to the device) -- and even if it passes this step, but you've got a branded device, it might get stuck in step 3 (which most likely is what happened to you).

The only way out if got stuck in steps 2 or 3 is checking for custom ROMs. As that "getting stuck" also affects developers, they often decide to build their own ROMs. Many times this is done by porting a ROM from compatible devices, adjusting the missing stuff (or leaving some gaps, so there *might* be things not fully working, which then is pointed out in the instructions).

So if you want to go the "do-it-yourself" way (after having t-mobile unlocking the device, if needed), check [How do I root my Samsung Galaxy S?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20292/16575) for how to root your SGS, and [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for fitting ROMs. The "how-to-flash" usually is described on the page you can download the ROM from.