# Failed to root Galaxy S (Fascinate) after three methods

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, rooting, root-access, usb-debugging

I have tried three methods for rooting my previous Android device, running 2.3.5 (Gingerbread). It's a Verizon Samsung Galaxy s (Fascinate - SCH-I500).

I have all the drivers installed for the device on my computer (Windows 8) and have USB Debug toggled. SuperOneClick failed to work after three attempts. Local rooting (No computer used) did not work either as that only rooted it about five seconds *after* boot, displaying a message on the home screen. The last method involved installing and app from the Play store and some software for my PC which I have forgot the name. I'm at a loss on how to root it so I can flash a custom ROM I have.

I had a general idea on where to start but as you've just read, all has failed. Side note: during all of these methods the SD Card was in phone but never mounted as per all the various instructions.

How can I root this reluctant device?

Comment: Did you take a look at our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) (linked from the 'rooting' tag)? It lists [How do I root my Samsung Galaxy S?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20292/16575). Tried that method? (I might be wrong with this suggestion, as there are multiple variants of the Galaxy S around, but it's worth a look).

Comment: I have tried that method. No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you describe your *Samsung Fascinate* is running Gingerbread, there's a rooting guide provided at [TheUnlockr](http://theunlockr.com/2012/11/09/how-to-root-the-samsung-fascinate-odin-method/) which you could try. It uses the [odin](/questions/tagged/odin) tool to root the device, so you would need [Odin Tool](http://www.galaxyforums.net/forum/fascinate-rs-guides/1967-how-root-froyo-gingerbread-your-fascinate.html), [Samsung Drivers](http://www.galaxyforums.net/forum/fascinate-rs-guides/1967-how-root-froyo-gingerbread-your-fascinate.html), [ClockworkMod Recovery](http://www.galaxyforums.net/forum/fascinate-rs-guides/1967-how-root-froyo-gingerbread-your-fascinate.html), and [Superuser](http://www.galaxyforums.net/forum/fascinate-rs-guides/1967-how-root-froyo-gingerbread-your-fascinate.html) for this.

Install the *Samsung drivers* first, then install *ClockworkMod* (which is where *Odin* is needed). Copy *SuperUser* to your SDCard, then boot into CWM (turn off the device, simultaneously hold <kbd>Vol +</kbd> + <kbd>Vol -</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>). Select *install zip from sdcard*, then *choose zip from sdcard*. Chose the *SuperUser* file you've copied to your SDCard. Let it flash, and reboot using the *reboot system now* menu entry. Your device now should be rooted.

Comment: Looks like this worked? Then I should see to add it to the [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) :)